# Difficulty getting ionic emulate android to work

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, ionic-framework

I have been successfully emulating my ionic project with ios but am unable to get it to come up on the Android emulator on my Mac. I get the following error from ionic:

```html
/Users/billnoble/documents/cues/code/current/Cues-App/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Target 'WQVGA400' not found, unable to run project
Error: /Users/billnoble/documents/cues/code/current/Cues-App/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

I have the Android SDK installed and skins installed in the library/android/sdk/platforms/android-22/skins directory. I have checked that the WQVGA400 skin is in there.

The ionic command I am issuing is:

```html
ionic emulate android --target="WQVGA400"
```

Am I missing a step?

Comment: You have to create a virtual machine with `android avd`, then use the name you gave it in your `target` parameter.

Comment: Brilliant thanks. I thought there was a step missing. Works now.